# Unable to create a Wired Connection in Ubuntu 18.04 graphically

Tags: wired, broadband

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10. In Windows, I can use the broadband connection right away without while the Ethernet RJ45 LAN Jack. But in Ubuntu, I am unable to find suitable options in **Settings** option. 
No suitable options to make Wired Connection.

[image]

In Ubuntu 16.04, I used to add new connection from **Edit Connections..** option. Is there any other way that I can make the wired connection working properly?

Comment: You are using an ethernet card. This is more a question about that that your broadband connection. So what is your ethernet card ? It seems  to be not recognized.  What is the output of `sudo lshw -c net` ?

Comment: Solved the problem in the following way: 
At first using 'sudo lshw -c net' identified the Ethernet interface 'enp2s0'. Then made an edit by opening the  'sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces'. Inserted the following lines:
'auto enp2s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp'